# Android App Connecting to Database Remotely

Tags: java, android, database

I'm not new to Java or databases, but I am new to Android app development. I have an app idea and have started to put it together. It's a very simple game that I would eventually like to have multiplayer capabilities.

The part of this process that I am pretty clueless about is the backend portion of the application. I need a database that will store things like usernames and passwords, scores, and things of that sort. I will also need to store things that I will need for the game in here. The application will rely very much on the database and it is important that any device has access to it and they are all looking at the same data.

If I've done my research right, this means that a simple SQL Lite database on the device itself isn't going to help me. Ideally, I would use SQL Server and create the database, as that's what I use for other projects... but I have no idea if this is possible or ideal.

I really just need somebody to steer me in the right direction here. I want something simple that can be accessed easily by any device at any time.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to write a server application which the various clients connect to. This server would be responsible for processing information given to it by clients and returning appropriate data back.

Exposing the database directly would be unwise; it would allow inventive players to cheat your system (or worse!) because they would have unfettered access to anything your application does. Your own server application can ensure that only reasonable access to the data store is permitted.

As for how you implement it, there are any number of choices. Web services are popular these days (in which case ASP.NET is the likely fit with SQL Server), but you can implement your own, non-HTTP, game protocol if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This definitely gives me a direction to head in. I've worked a lot with the ASP.NET/C#/SQL Server combination, so that would be ideal. I'm really glad to hear that it's possible to do that.

Are there any good tutorials that you could point me to for building a ASP.NET web service that could be used in conjunction with an Android app?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Android isn't special in this way. Write a web service that uses some format you can easily find an Android library for (like JSON), and then use the Android HTTP libraries to talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could access remote SQL database from Adnroid app using JDBC.

I've provided example here: [How to save image files to mysql with sql code and how to display them with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232857/how-to-save-image-files-to-mysql-with-sql-code-and-how-to-display-them-with-java/15234570#15234570)

The only difference I've encountered using JDBC in desktop and android apps that in Android You have to perform JDBC operations in a separate thread, like any other network operation in Android.

Comment: Possible, yes. Almost certainly an unwise decision, though.