# Java Android: BufferedInputStream to byte Array

Tags: java, android, stream, arrays, bufferedinputstream

Has anyone an idea how to get a BufferedInputStream to a byte[] so that I can make a Bitmap of it?

That's my Stream:

```
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

And that's my byte[]:

```
byte[] bytes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uhm... the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read) method of the `BufferedInputStream` will give you the `byte[]` you need.

For getting a `Bitmap`, use the [`BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream) method and pass in your `BufferedInputStream` as a parameter. Good to go ! :)

Comment: So just; byte[] bytes = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);?

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)`

Comment: +1 For the most right answer. For transparent images (such as: .png), I think you need to specify `BitmapFactory.Options`.

Comment: Seems to work but if i want to put the ImageView in to my LinearLayout it says: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views
How to fix this?

Comment: Ah, for that you need to use [`Handler.post()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post)`. Different question, altogether :)

Comment: @LittleChild You should include the main looper: `new Handel(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(runnable);`

Answer (score 2):

Use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html):

```
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int theByte;

while((theByte = stream.read()) != -1) baos.write(theByte);
```

[Then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004271/597657):

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inDither = true;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
byte[] imageByteArray = bytes;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length, opt);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` because *so that I can make a Bitmap of it* :p

Comment: Still very complex :D Just pass in the stream to `decodeStream()` and let Android do the magic ;) It is overloaded. :)

Comment: @LittleChild Yeah agreed! Too lazy to update it twice :P

Comment: I tried this now but then it says NullPointerException for outputstream write at:
while((theByte = is.read()) != -1) baos.write(bytes);
i think "is" should mean stream right?