# Java BufferedImage Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedimage

I have classes of Server, Client, and Message. The Message class consists of the server name, the client name, BufferedImage, commands, and so on. What I would like to do is to store a BufferedImage from Server to Message as a serialized byte form, send Message to Client, and deserialize the BufferedImage within Message after receiving it in Client class. I want to ask how it can be done, because all I could find was to send the BufferedImage directly from Server to Client.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to serialize an image (compatible with Swing) from Java to Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994129/what-is-the-best-way-to-serialize-an-image-compatible-with-swing-from-java-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the message instance in an `ObjectOutputStream`.
Just define the `Message` class with all fields to serialize and 
store  the `BufferedImage` in a byte representation.

From the server side you can write the message in the outputstream in this way:

```
OutputStream outputStreamServer = ...;
byte[] bufferedImage = ...
Message message = new Message(bufferedImage, name, ...);
ObjectOutputStream ObjectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStreamServer);
ObjectOS.writeObject(message);
```

In this way, from the client side, you can read the server stream by using an `ObjectInputStream` and get a `Message` instance.
And when the client wishes, he can unserialize the bytes to a `BufferedImage` :

```
 ObjectInputStream ObjectIS = new ObjectInputStream (inputStreamClient);
 Message message = (Message) ObjectIS.readObject();
 ...
 // where unserializeBufferedImage() is a custom method to do the unserialization
 BufferedImage image = message.unserializeBufferedImage();
```